# Inserting using PDO bindValue in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindvalue

I am trying to use the PDO bindValue but its not working on my side.

```
 public static function insert($tableName, $columnValues = array()) {
        $columns = array_keys ( $columnValues );
        $columns = '`' . implode ( '`,`', $columns ) . '`';
        $values = null;
        $x = 1;
        $y = 1;
        foreach ( $columnValues as $value ) {
            $values .= '?';
            if ($x < count ( $columnValues )) {
                $values .= ',';
            }
            $x ++;
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$tableName} ($columns) VALUES($values)" . '</br>';
        if ($sqlString = DatabaseConnection::getConnectionInstance ()->pdo->prepare ( $sql )) {
            foreach ( $columnValues as $value ) {
                $sqlString->bindValue ( $y, $value );
                $y ++;
            }
            if ($sqlString->execute ()) {
                echo 'executed';
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried this one?
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your function to use lazy binding see [**PDO info**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).
NOTE your `implode()` was not quite right.
I have added echos to show results wich you should remove after testing.

```
public static function insert($tableName, $columnValues = array()) {
        $columns = array_keys( $columnValues );
        $params = array_values( $columnValues );// Array to hold values for lazy binding
        $columns = '`' . implode ("`,`",  $columns ) . '`';
        $values = null;
        $x = 1;/*
        $y = 1;*/
        foreach ( $columnValues as $value ) {
            $values .= '?';
            if ($x < count ( $columnValues )) {
                $values .= ',';
            }
            $x ++;
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$tableName} ($columns) VALUES($values)" . '</br>';
        if ($sqlString = DatabaseConnection::getConnectionInstance ()->pdo->prepare ( $sql )) {
            echo $sql;//For Testing
            echo "<br>";//For Testing
            var_dump($params);//For Testing
           if ($sqlString->execute ($params)) {
                echo 'executed';
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This function produces

```
INSERT INTO test (`Peter`,`Ben`,`Joe`) VALUES(?,?,?)

array(3) { [0]=> int(35) [1]=> int(37) [2]=> int(43) }
```

From

```
$columnValues =  array("Peter"=>35, "Ben"=>37, "Joe"=>43);
$tableName ="test";   
insert($tableName, $columnValues)
```

Comment: I had to change the function to evade the bindValue since no eror and no +ve result.thanks

Comment: No `bindValue()` in my function?

Comment: i tried the function david strachan but there was no +ve result

Comment: What results from `echo $sql`& `var_dump($params)`

Comment: $sql is                                                                                                                                        INSERT INTO users (`username`,`password`) VALUES(?,?) and var_damp is                                                                                                                      array (size=2)
  0 => int 23456789
  1 => int 234567

Comment: the sql string is ok but the problem is that its not executed